# Running Pow & MAMP Pro Simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mamp

I just switched from using Passenger to using POW because I didn't have to run the Apache server to run rails apps on POW. But I'm not having luck running MAMP Pro and POW simultaneously.

Anyone have any luck running both MAMP Pro and POW?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is another way that I prefer. You don't have to mess with scripts or anything —much. The downside is, you need to have MAMP Pro running to access your Pow apps.

First, if you have Pow installed (which, in your case, you do), uninstall it with `curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh`. Not to worry, all settings and applications will be preserved.

Then, you have to add a line to Pow configuration file. Do `echo 'export POW_DST_PORT=88' >> ~/.powconfig`, and then install Pow again with `curl get.pow.cx | sh`.

Now, open MAMP Pro, go to Hosts, and create a new host. Doesn't matter what it is named and which directory is selected (though I use 'rails.dev' and the folder I keep my Rails apps in). (Also, deselect the select box for "local name resolution", just in case.) Then go to the Advanced tab, and fill this in to the textarea labeled "Customized virtual host general settings":

```
ServerName pow
ServerAlias *.dev

ProxyPass / http://localhost:20559/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:20559/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

This is a solution derived from the [Running Pow with Apache article](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Running-Pow-with-Apache) on 37signals' github wiki, and it works fine on the great MAMP Pro 1.9.X for Snow Leopard as well as the dreadful MAMP Pro 2.0.X on Lion.

Comment: Keep in mind - with this MAMP has to be running at all times to access your `*.dev` sites, otherwise you'll have to go to `*.dev:88`

Comment: Thanks this is great. I feel like I switch back and forth between MAMP and Pow all the time. So to have MAMP on all the time is no biggie.

Comment: Actually with MAMP Pro 2, Pow works without having to do the steps you gave above. I just upgraded and tried it.

Comment: I'm running MP 2.0.5 and Pow caused my other sites that I run through MP to not run. The solution given above worked perfectly. I am now a happy camper!

Comment: Just for the record, I am running MAMP PRO 3.0.5 and this solution still works. The only modification is that in the new MAMP host configuration that is described, it is no longer the "Advanced tab", it is the "Extended" tab and it is "Additional parameters for <VirtualHost>" instead of "Customized virtual host general settings." I'm running Pow 0.4.3 and they are both playing nicely together.

Comment: Running MAMP 3.3 Free version (not pro) and simply added the above code between a `<VirtualHost *:80>` block inside my Apache config file and it works like it says on the box.

Answer (score 3):

There is a shell script if you need to switch between running Pow and Apache: https://gist.github.com/919084

And another script in ruby that changes Pow's listening port, so you can still run Apache on port 80: https://gist.github.com/911687

Also, I would suggest you to install [powder](https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder) gem

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above if you find that your local ip is now forwarding to POW rather than apache, you need to add a blank virtualhost entry to catch all traffic.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 #This is blank
</VirtualHost>
```