# How to run Pow.CX alongside MAMP and VirtualHostX

Tags: apache, mamp, rack, rack-pow

I have come across some some answers [on StackOverflow similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010104/running-pow-mamp-pro-simultaneously), however they pertain to MAMP Pro. My particular setup of consists of the standard MAMP alongside VirtualHostX (VHX).

I don't intend to purchase MAMP Pro, MAMP & VHX fulfil my needs. I am running Mac OSX 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion).

Currently Installed applications:

- [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html): 2.1.1 running on port 8888 (MySQL on 8889)
- [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) (4.0.6)
- [Anvil](http://anvilformac.com/)

I have previously installed [Pow.cx](http://pow.cx/) and Anvil but this caused my MAMP sites to stop resolving. All traffic was routed to Pow over port 80.

I uninstalled Pow, changed the ports on MAMP back to their default ports, and now they resolve correctly.

How can I continue to run MAMP, and add hosts via VirtualHostX, whilst also running Pow & Anvil?

What steps do I need to take before I install Pow again, and would I need to do anything post install?

Would I need to add any rules into VHX to stop the clash?

Comment: I should add that I also have [hostbuddy](http://clickontyler.com/hostbuddy/) installed if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got MAMP and Pow (via Anvil) running together with the following setup:

1. Set MAMP's Apache port to 8888.
2. In VirtualHostX, set your application's port to 8888 and any tld other than `.dev`.

You can now access your Pow apps at `<appname>.dev` and your MAMP apps at the domain you set up in VHX (`.site` is my setup), plus the port number on the end. For instance, I have a Pow application setup at `mysite.dev` and MAMP application setup at `mysite.site:8888`.

It's not ideal, since you have to have the port number on the end of the URL. But at least you can use both Pow and MAMP now without conflicts.

Comment: Additionally, with this configuration you don't need MAMP running to see Pow sites and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob, I hope your solution works well for others too. I still use Anvil, also Virtualhost X is still a great solution. I've since moved across to using vagrant boxes for development which I find to be less of a pain to setup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a default Vagrant setup (Chef or Puppet configuration) you work from?

Comment: Since I only ever need to use the software on my machine, I simply setup a basic vagrant box. I think Puppet/Chef is overkill when its just one machine. I followed various tutorials to get Ruby/Node/LAMP etc working. I found this article to be a good starting point [http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/09/17/setup-a-simple-ruby-2-on-rails-4-environment-with-vagrant-and-virtual-box/](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/09/17/setup-a-simple-ruby-2-on-rails-4-environment-with-vagrant-and-virtual-box/)

Answer (score 2):

I found this and it worked for me:

https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Running-Pow-with-Apache

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that tonight!

Answer (score 1):

There is a different approach that allows to use default port 80 on both servers.

You will need to add an additional ip address to loopback interface and bind the second web server to this new ip address.

For example on my Mac machine the loopback interface is named lo0

So to add a new IP address I do:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2
```

Then in Apache/MAMP config depending on what do you use replace

```
Listen *:80
```

or

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

respectively with

```
Listen 127.0.0.2:80
```

or

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80
```

Then you can run pow with its default settings

You can also create a domain name for 127.0.0.2 in your /etc/hosts

Example:

```
127.0.0.2 webserver2
```

P.S. This approach can be implemented on Linux and Windows too.